# how to match to data based on several condition

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(DES = c("AAAAA", "ABBBB", "BBDDD", "CHDDD", "NMHH", 
"YNNN", "UUUU", "IMMM", "TTSGG", "MHDDD", "IIKKKKK", "UDDDD", 
"AAAAA", "ABBBB"), Name = c("AB1", "TH1", "TH2", "HUA", "HUA1", 
"UMA", "YIN", "YIM", "IUMH", "YIMH", "YIH", "TH2", "AB1", "TH1"
), data = c(1.399260301, 1.435057306, 1.515715678, 1.157216398, 
1.452347714, 1.172466387, 1.16325675, 2.614138423, 0.895228818, 
1.571925745, 1.717242238, 1.572841664, 0.924094104, 1.59458932
), Exact = c(0.000536206, 0.000910058, 0.001145037, 0.00114666, 
0.001883335, 0.002365192, 0.002548559, 0.003406673, 0.004232483, 
0.005164572, 0.006269242, 0.006741774, 0.009565493, 0.009581586
), Class = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

now I have another data which looks like this

```
df2<- structure(list(DES = c("AAAAA", "ABBBB", "BBDDD", "CHDDD"), Name = c("AB1", 
"TH1", "TH2", "HUA")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

I am trying to get where those ones in the df2 are situated in the df1
so I do this

```
match(df$DES,df2$DES)
```

but I am interested in those with Class 1

I do this

```
match(df$DES,df2$DES) && df$Class ==1
```

I basically dont know how to subset based on class 1 , I also tried several other ways but didn't work like `subset(match(df$DES,df2$DES), Class==1)`

Comment: @akrun
I want to use `match` and none of the above work. I only want the CLASS 1 match

Comment: `df2[ df2$DES %in% df$DES & df2$Class == 1L,]`?

Comment: @r2evans this is much better `df2[ df2$DES %in% df$DES & df$Class == 1L,]`

Comment: @akrun
no I need to get the index of them, I need to know the row number

Comment: @nik if you need the index, just wrap with `which` on the logical vector

Comment: @nik that is not correct code, try `df2[ df2$DES %in% df$DES[df$Class == 1L],]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this to find the indices ,

```
match(df[df$Class == 1 , ]$DES,df2$DES)
```

then

```
df2[na.omit(match(df[df$Class == 1 , ]$DES,df2$DES)), ]
    DES Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on `dplyr::inner_join`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

inner_join(df2, df %>% rownames_to_column) %>%
  filter(Class == 1) %>% pull(rowname) %>% as.numeric

#> Joining, by = c("DES", "Name")
#> [1] 1 2 3 4
```

---

To get `Class == 2`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

inner_join(df2, df %>% rownames_to_column) %>%
  filter(Class == 2) %>% pull(rowname) %>% as.numeric

#> Joining, by = c("DES", "Name")
#> [1] 13 14
```

Comment: I am only interested in their index (I only want to know which rows they are that are in class 1 )

Comment: Please, see my updated solution, @nik.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to r2evans--just noticed that this is the same as his comment, just wrapped in `which` as akrun suggested.

```
df2<- data.frame(DES = c("AAAAA", "ABBBB", "BBDDD", "CHDDD"), Name = c("AB1", "TH1", "TH2", "HUA"))
which((df$DES %in% df2$DES) & (df$Class == 1L))
#> [1] 1 2 3 4
which((df$DES %in% df2$DES) & (df$Class == 2L))
#> [1] 13 14
```

Comment: `match(df2$DES, df$DES[df$Class == 2L])` check this one, it again give you the index for the first class

Comment: @nik Of course. My mistake. The answer's been updated.